# Google Search console reporting Soft 404 for existing pages

Tags: php, reactjs, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

I have recently made a new website. Now Google Search console is reporting Soft 404 for pages that actually exist.

I didn't have this problems on the previous website that was server side rendered with PHP. The new website is React based and I believe this is the problem but I still haven't found the true nature of the problem.

Is anyone experiencing similar problems?